# Is there a resource that describes the different parts and ways to run different workflow in SP 2013 w/ SPD?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm new to SharePoint.  I can't find a resource that will help me understand the different types of actions, steps, etc in a Workflow.  Any resource you have that's help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft documentation? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-workflows-included-with-SharePoint-d74fcceb-3a64-40fb-9904-cc33ca49da56
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-a-workflow-f6a92a4b-c919-40d7-9728-2e79c524764c

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx

Comment: Yes, but I'm so new, it's not very helpful.  I'm looking for something to break down the different actions, give definitions and how to put them together successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a list of workflow actions & descriptions available in Designer 2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164026.aspx

And here is an overview from Microsoft on creating list workflows in SPD:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx